# RecyclerView horizontal items are no aligned

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to align my items in a recyclerView, but I'm not getting results.
How could I do that?

My xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCod"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:text="Codigo"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtPrecoFim"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtData_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTipoPagamento"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

it displays like that:
[image]

Comment: you have to fix width of view or use weightsums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set android:layout_width="0dp" to all of your text views.

here is an example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: exapmle]